# Use of gerunds to mean "because"

Tags: terminology

While proofreading this sentence:

> They awaited their deliverance with unwavering hope, ***because they knew*** that the public opinion was in their favour.

I replaced ***because they knew*** with ***knowing***:

> They awaited their deliverance with unwavering hope, ***knowing*** that the public opinion was in their favour.

Does this use of the gerund ***knowing*** as meaning ***because** they knew* have a name? Can I call it ***causal***?

Comment: It doesn't always mean "because". It just means "while". For example: "They awaited the rescue helicopter, expecting that the waves could overturning their boat at any time."

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I am not saying at all that it **always** means that. I am asking, what do you call its use when it **does** mean "because".

Comment: The "because" PP would indicate semantic reason and hence can be called a 'reason adjunct'. The gerund-participial clause is an adjunct, though I'm not sure what semantic subtype it belongs to.Possibly a peripheral case of a depictive adjunct referring to the referent of "they".

Comment: Thank you, @BillJ, I was hoping you would pass by and leave a comment as the grammar expert you seem to be. So, are you saying my "knowing that the public opinion was in their favour"  clause does not express reason? I am not familiar with English grammar terminology. Does "depictive adjunct" mean that this clause modifies "they" as a relative clause would?

Comment: That's right. Reason adjuncts are expressed with PPs headed by words like "because" or "since". No, depictive adjuncts are not modifying relative clauses; they simply 'refer' to some element, usually the subject. The best we can say is that it's a supplementary adjunct, possibly a depictive one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [BBC.Co.UK World Service](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv305.shtml):

> Participial clauses often express
>
> - condition
> - reason
> - cause
> - result
> - time
>
> in a similar way to full adverbial clauses, only more economically.

[And, as one would expect, with greater scope for ambiguity.]

The examples you give perhaps not too obviously express **reason** in the first instance (ie explaining why) rather than cause ('They awaited their deliverance with unwavering hope, *the reason for this being that* they knew that the public opinion was in their favour').

While the adjective 'causal' is certainly twinned with 'cause' and used to express the semantic relation, I wouldn't use 'rational' here, preferring 'expressing reason'.

Comment: So there is no term which would fill in the blank in: "The ______ use of the gerund"?

Comment: You'll doubtless see 'rational' used this way in some articles. But even the hits for searches for [causal + temporal + rational] I've tried use 'rational' in the 'logical' or 'sound-minded' senses. OED will have the 'related to the reason something is chosen/done' sense. // I'd insert 'dubious' in your template (I don't use 'gerund' as it's variously and hence unhelpfully defined).

Answer (score 1):

> They awaited their deliverance with unwavering hope, because they knew that the public opinion was in their favour.
>
> I replaced because they knew with knowing:
>
> They awaited their deliverance with unwavering hope, knowing that the public opinion was in their favour.

*because they knew that the public opinion was in their favour.* is a subordinate clause of **reason**, adverbially modifying *They awaited their deliverance with unwavering hope* (I would call it a “free modifier”)

*knowing that the public opinion was in their favour.* is a participle clause of **state**, adverbially modifying *They awaited their deliverance with unwavering hope* (I would call it a “free modifier”)

It is basically the same as *in the knowledge that the public opinion was in their favour.*

“Knowing” and “because” are quite different and do not mean the same thing at all. If you change one for the other, the meaning of the sentence changes.

“Knowing” can be replaced by a variety of participles “shouting”, believing, holding, repeating, etc. none of which give a reason.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Cannot a clause of **state** express reason? I find this fascinating. In my mother tongue there is no ambiguity: both structures express reason.

Comment: One may deduce the 'reason' aspect in OP's example as other interpretations would be infelicitous.

Comment: @fev *Cannot a clause of state express reason?* Er... wouldn't it then be a clause of reason, and not one of state? In your example, the **reason** for their awaiting deliverance is **because they wanted to be delivered**. The **state** they were in as they waited was one of **knowing**